# ftp sending python bytesio stream

Tags: python, file, memory, ftplib, bytesio

I want to send a file with python ftplib, from one ftp site to another, so to avoid file read/write processees.

I create a BytesIO stream:

```
myfile=BytesIO()
```

And i succesfully retrieve a image file from ftp site one with retrbinary:

```
ftp_one.retrbinary('RETR P1090080.JPG', myfile.write)
```

I can save this memory object to a regular file:

```
fot=open('casab.jpg', 'wb')

fot=myfile.readvalue()
```

But i am not able to send this stream via ftp with storbinary. I thought this would work:

```
ftp_two.storbinary('STOR magnafoto.jpg', myfile.getvalue())
```

But doesnt. i get a long error msg ending with 'buf = fp.read(blocksize)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

I also tried many absurd combinations, but with no success. As an aside, I am also quite puzzled with what I am really doing with myfoto.write. Shouldnt it be myfoto.write() ?

I am also quite clueless to what this buffer thing does or require. Is what I want too complicated to achieve? Should I just ping pong the files with an intermediate write/read in my system? Ty all

EDIT: thanks to abanert I got things straight. For the record, storbinary arguments were wrong and a myfile.seek(0) was needed to 'rewind' the stream before sending it. This is a working snippet that moves a file between two ftp addresses without intermediate physical file writes:

```
import ftplib as ftp
from io import BytesIO

ftp_one=ftp.FTP(address1, user1, pass1)
ftp_two=ftp.FTP(address2, user2, pass2)
myfile=BytesIO()
ftp_one.retrbinary ('RETR imageoldname.jpg', myfile.write)
myfile.seek(0)
ftp_two.storbinary('STOR imagenewname.jpg', myfile)
ftp_one.close()
ftp_two.close()
myfile.close()
```

Comment: Side note: The "I can save this memory object to a regular file" doesn't actually save the information at all. `fot=open('casab.jpg', 'wb')` creates a new empty file, then `fot=myfile.readvalue()` forgets about the file object, replacing it with a string. You need something like `fot.write(myfile.readvalue())` to actually write to a file. (You may or may not need to `myfile.seek(0)` first, as well.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint that BytesIO streams need to be "rewinded" with seek(0)! This fixed my issue that the upload worked but the file was empty \o/

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you're calling `getvalue()`. Just don't do that:

```
ftp_two.storbinary('STOR magnafoto.jpg', myfile)
```

---

[`storbinary`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.storbinary) requires a file-like object that it can call `read` on.

Fortunately, you have just such an object, `myfile`, a [`BytesIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO). (It's not entirely clear from your code what the sequence of things is here—if this doesn't work as-is, you may need to `myfile.seek(0)` or create it in a different mode or something. But a `BytesIO` will work with `storbinary` unless you do something wrong.)

But instead of passing `myfile`, you pass `myfile.getvalue()`. And [`getvalue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue) "Returns `bytes` containing the entire contents of the buffer."

So, instead of giving `storbinary` a file-like object that it can call `read` on, you're giving it a `bytes` object, which is of course the same as `str` in Python 2.x, and you can't call `read` on that.

---

For your aside:

> As an aside, I am also quite puzzled with what I am really doing with myfoto.write. Shouldnt it be myfoto.write() ?

Look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrbinary). The second parameter isn't a file, it's a callback function.

> The *callback* function is called for each block of data received, with a single string argument giving the data block.

What you want is a function that appends each block of data to the end of `myfoto`. While you could write your own function to do that:

```
def callback(block_of_data):
    myfoto.write(block_of_data)
```

… it should be pretty obvious that this function does exactly the same thing as the `myfoto.write` method. So, you can just pass that method itself.

If you don't understand about bound methods, see [Method Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects) in the tutorial.

---

This flexibility, as weird as it seems, lets you do something even better than downloading the whole file into a buffer to send to another server. You can actually open the two connections at the same time, and use callbacks to send each buffer from the source server to the destination server as it's received, without ever storing anything more than one buffer.

But, unless you really need that, you probably don't want to go through all that complexity.

In fact, in general, `ftplib` is kind of low-level. And it has some designs (like the fact that `storbinary` takes a file, while `retrbinary` takes a callback) that make total sense at that low level but seem very odd from a higher level. So, you may want to look at some of the higher-level libraries by doing a [search at PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=ftp&submit=search).

Comment: I did that, passed myfile to storbinary. It does create a file, but 0 bytes long.

Comment: @jose: Well, you'll have to post a complete example if you want it debugged, but the most likely possibility is the one I already mentioned in the answer: If you create an empty read-write `BytesIO`, then write into it, then read from it, you're reading from the end, so there's nothing to read. You can fix that by either creating a new readable `BytesIO` out of the writable `BytesIO`'s buffer, or just calling `seek(0)` on it.

Comment: yes, this makes sense. I will check tomorrow. Its my fault to toy with file streams without studying them properly. I had no clue these streams have a read position. Ty for your help

Comment: Toying with them is a great way to learn. Maybe try toying with small ones in the interactive interpreter, where you can directly see what's going on at each step, instead of trying to guess based on the effects of a larger program interacting with a server. But don't give up on learning by experiment in general!

Comment: Ok, tried, and a simple myfile.seek(0) made things work. Thanks, abanert, gonna edit main post to save to future. I do toy with tools in Idle, but with two handicaps (misreading the arguments in storbinary and ignoring the need to 'rewind' data streams) I was quite lost.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, you just saved me a bunch of time!